# JSON post from c# fails with 500 error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a c# winforms app in which I'm trying to call into a web service for which I control the code (on both ends). I know the web service is fine because I can call it from jquery with no problems and valid json is returned. But when I call it from c#, I get this error: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." In the debugger I cannot glean any more details than that.

Here is my c# caller code:

```
private string GetMemberCheckInData() {
    string response = string.Empty;
    string fullURL = RootServiceURL + "MemberCheckIn";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(fullURL);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
        string json = "{\"scanCode\":\"" + APIKey + "\"," +
            "\"siteID\":\"2\"," +
            "\"revenueGroupID\":\"0\"," +
            "\"employeeID\":\"12345\"}";;

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
            response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Here is the literal JSON that is being sent:

```
{"scanCode":"***8G9V3MA39H0N****","siteID":"2","revenueGroupID":"0","employeeID":"12345"}
```

Here is the c# web service code (works fine when called from jquery):

```
[WebMethod]
public void MemberCheckIn(string scanCode, int siteID, int revenueGroupID, int employeeID)
{
   ...code is never reached...
}
```

The web service function is never actually entered; I confirmed this with the debugger. When I call it from jquery, I can debug right into it. So it seems the request is being rejected by the .net runtime or IIS or something.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webmethod is expecting you to pass parameters in to it.

```
string fullURL = RootServiceUrl + "MemberCheckIn?scanCode=X&siteID=1...etc.
```

Comment: I just tried that but got the same 500 error. And I'm wondering also about streamWriter.Write(json), which apparently should just be sending an empty string?? I tried sending an empty string, and also tried removing that line altogether. All same result, 500 error.

Comment: Check your fullURL path.  Since I can't see the RootServiceUrl you may have an issue with the path.

Comment: I scrapped the json stuff and did a more traditional post, and it worked. But you're right, simple NVPs work fine.